# Importing an Excel file into an existing sqli file using c#

Tags: c#, sql, windows, forms

I'm sort of new to programming and I have been trying to make some program for some friends but I just can't figure out how to import an excel file to SQL using c#... The problem I'm having is that I just can't seem to find a decent Explainanten on the internet that might be able to help me out.

Is there any decent tutorial/code that you guys know of that might be able to help me?

NOTE: I don't need a tutorial per se but rather a code or something so that I have some reference to work with.

Thanks for taking the time.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

you can use Nuget Packages like this:
IronXL.Excel

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for taking your time and answer! I've found another solution and a video tutorial that guided me pretty much well enough to figure things out my self.

The solution that I found was installing the Microsoft excel package and then exporting the cell value into a string whilst using a while loop to import it into the database. You can also use an Array the same way to make the process go a little faster. 

Again, thanks for your time!